# Getting forces that are acting on a Body

Tags: c#, xna, farseer

Since I am building a physics teaching platform, I need to know the total force that is acting on an object at the moment. This way, I may draw arrows showing this resultant force for students to understand what is going on.

I dug into the source of Farseer and found the **internal Vector2 variable *Force***. Since it is internal, I cannot access it from my teaching platform since they are in different assemblies.

Will anything bad happen if I change the modifier to, let's say private, and add a getter function to it?

OR

Is there a better way to get the resultant force currently acting on an object?

Comment: If you can't access it because it is internal then you want to make it public, not private. Since you are just modifying the source, you may want to just leave the variable alone and create your own property to return the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems you have access to the source, the easiest approach to expose that variable is to add a public getter to the class in which it resides.  An instance of that class will have access to the internal variable.

**EDIT**: (Added code examples)

It is all about where the code accessing the internal value exists. Hopefully the example below will illustrate this for you. Assume that you have a solution with two projects, one called ExternalAssembly, the other MyApplication. MyApplication has a reference to ExternalAssembly to access its classes.

Project:  ExternalAssembly

```
namespace ExternalAssembly
{
    public class MyClass 
    {
        internal string hiddenString;

        public MyClass() 
        {
            this.hiddenString = "This is my value.";
        }

        public string Exposed
        {
            get { return this.hiddenString; }
        }
    }

    public class MyClass2
    {
        private MyClass classInstance;

        public MyClass2()
        {
            this.classInstance = new MyClass();
        }

        public string Exposed2 
        {
            get { return this.classInstance.hiddenString; }
        }
    }
}
```

Project:  MyApplication

```
namespace MyApplication
{
    using ExternalAssembly;

    public class CallInternalTest() 
    {
        MyClass classInstance = new MyClass();
        MyClass2 class2Instance = new MyClass2();

        // this will fail since hiddenString is an internal variable
        Console.WriteLine(classInstance.hiddenString);

        // this will succeed since Exposed is a public member
        Console.WriteLine(classInstance.Exposed);

        // this will also succeed since Exposed2 is a public member
        Console.WriteLine(class2Instance.Exposed2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't an "internal" variable inaccessible outside the assembly? Shouldn't I change the modifier too?

Comment: I updated my answer, hopefully the code will help you to understand.